# Ruby on Rails Association with model many-to-many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

i`m beginner with RoR and trying to handle my many-many Association

i handled the relationship between my models and the migration

Trip model

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :relationships
has_many :topics, through: :relationships
end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :relationships
has_many :trips, through: :relationships
end
```

relationship model

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :trip
end
```

my migration

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :relationships do |t|
    t.belongs_to :user
    t.belongs_to :trip
    t.timestamps
end
add_index :relationships, :user_id
add_index :relationships, :trip_id
end
end
```

User_controller

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController


 before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]



def trips
@user = User.find(params[:id])
 @trips = @user.trips

end
def index
@users = User.all
end

  def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end
def new
@user = User.new
@trips = Trip.all
end
def edit
end
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end



def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update(user_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end


def destroy
@user.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
 end
 end

private

def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end


def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name)
end
end
```

i don`t know how to assign Trip to User and where write the assign in the controller or in the form ??

@user.trips << @trip Not work

Answer (score 0):

Changed in the modal as :--

Trip model

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :relationships
has_many :users, through: :relationships
end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :relationships
has_many :trips, through: :relationships
end
```

And then try like that:-

```
@user.trips << @trip
```